# Unable to save file on Cloud Shell editor beta

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I am finding that the **cloud shell editor** is not saving my python file. I can see a circle as opposed to the X near the file name

[image]

When click save, it still shows me the circle as opposed to the x. I have tried to save using auto save. That does not work, so I disabled auto save and tried to save manually (File menu approach). However, that does not work either.

I am using Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Version of the editor - theia-editor-for-cloudshell-preview 0.0.1

Running df -h in the shell shows

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          36G   25G   11G  71% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           848M     0  848M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        36G   25G   11G  71% /root
/dev/sdb1       4.8G  376M  4.2G   9% /home
overlayfs       1.0M  124K  900K  13% /etc/ssh/keys
tmpfs           848M  780K  847M   1% /run/metrics
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
overlayfs       1.0M  124K  900K  13% /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
tmpfs           848M     0  848M   0% /run/google/devshell
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with Chrome 71.0.3578.98. What browser and version are you using?

Comment: Your edit broke your picture. Are you using the new Cloud Shell Editor or the Legacy Editor?

Comment: Where (how) are you clicking save? (File menu, popup dialog, etc.)

Comment: I have tried over and over and I cannot reproduce your problem. Restart Cloud Shell and try again - don't close it, actually click the `Restart` selection.

Comment: restarting cloud shell now

Comment: no difference even after restart.

Comment: Do you have free space? Run `df` in the shell.

Comment: Wow - no idea now. I use Cloud Shell multiple times per day and I have never seen this problem. I have tried everything that I can think of and the editor works fine for me.

Comment: I wonder if it is because I have loaded multiple directories.

Comment: It loads everything in home directory right

Comment: What do you mean `I have loaded multiple directories`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186645/discussion-between-vinay-joseph-and-john-hanley).

Comment: What are the permissions of this file in the shell? (you can check by running the command `ls -la`) You should have user write permissions on this file, otherwise you won't be able to save it.